# Reinstalling Grub - shows no volume groups found, how do you fix this?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, system

I have a full backup which I had restored onto a new built system on Ubuntu 12.04
The backup did not include /dev /proc /sys folders.

Upon rebooting, the grub show the following errors

```
error: no such device: 0f7dccc8-120f-41bd-ae68-3b5a3c35ecb7
error: file not found
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Using the ubuntu 12.04 server cd, boot and select the rescue mode.
Execute a shell in `/dev/sda1` - which allows me to execute as on the system

update /etc/fstab with new system UUID

Reinstall Grub - which goes well until I do an `update-grub`

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
  No volume groups found
done
```

How do we fix this No volume groups, i.e. create a volume group

`fdisk -l` - shows there 3 partition. Only /dev/sda2 is where the data is?

```
/dev/sda1      Linux      - /boot as well / directory is
/dev/sda2      Extended    
/dev/sda5      Linux swap
```

Should I check for existing volume or partition and recreate.

Comment: Did your problem go away?